# Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component. Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.MultipartReaderStream

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I get an exception when I try to read multi part content from the request saying the content may have already been read by another component.

```
 if (MultipartRequestHelper.IsMultipartContentType(Request.ContentType))
            {
                // Used to accumulate all the form url encoded key value pairs in the 
                // request.
                var formAccumulator = new KeyValueAccumulator();

                var boundary = Request.GetMultipartBoundary();
                var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, HttpContext.Request.Body);
                var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();
                while (section != null)
                {
                    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition;
                    var hasContentDispositionHeader =
                        ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse(section.ContentDisposition, out contentDisposition);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It turns out that I had to disable form value model binding by using the attribute below.

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
```

The attribute implementation is below

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var factories = context.ValueProviderFactories;
        factories.RemoveType<FormValueProviderFactory>();
        factories.RemoveType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>();
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have like disabled every single factory by using `ValueProviderFactories.RemoveType<T>()` but its still giving me the Unexpected error

Comment: Yep, solved for me. It's because the `DisableFormValueModelBinding` custom filter allows us to prevent the method from trying to bind and validate the input automatically which would preemptively read the input stream. This allows us to later use `MultipartReader` to parse the `request.Body`.

Useful reference; https://blog.bitscry.com/2018/03/12/uploading-files-in-asp-net-core-from-an-mvc-view/

Comment: This answer helped me resolve an issue where I try to use bindings with ```UploadFilesAsync(String cst, String data, String device)```, before the multipart would throw exceptions due to being preempted by the bindings. Now it works as intended. Thanks!

Comment: how we disable `DisableFormValueModelBinding` while working in middleware startup.cs class . working in .net core 2.2 ?

Comment: I used attribute `[FromForm]` and got the error, which makes sense. Before i reach the line `var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, request.Body);`and `var section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync();` the attribute forced to open stream and exception will be thrown.

If i use `[FromQuery]` same error, but i am a little bit confused why it happens too? 

But solution worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

In **asp.net core 3**, You have to add `factories.RemoveType<FormFileValueProviderFactory>();` to your `DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute` attribute.

**Code**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var factories = context.ValueProviderFactories;
        factories.RemoveType<FormValueProviderFactory>();
        factories.RemoveType<FormFileValueProviderFactory>();
        factories.RemoveType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>();
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: This answer is useful and helped me while working on the DotNet core migration from 2.2 to 3.1. My API worked after added FormFileValueProviderFactory. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

In my specific case, I was using a multipart boundary value which didn't exist in the payload being parsed by the MultipartReader:

```
// multipartBoundary is not in the contents of httpResponseContentStream.
var multipartBoundary = "batchresponse_63d0e4c7-4d49-4961-a294-3902d1730c44";
var multipartReader = new MultipartReader(multipartBoundary, httpResponseContentStream);
// Unexpected end-of-stream error used to occur here:
var multipartSection = await multipartReader.ReadNextSectionAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Once the multipartBoundary was updated to reflect an actual boundary value present in the content being parsed, the code worked as expected.

Answer (score 5):

[This](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18087#issuecomment-626116782) worked for me for netcore 3.1

You need to add

```cs
factories.RemoveType<FormFileValueProviderFactory>();
```

on this method

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute : Attribute, IResourceFilter
{
    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        var factories = context.ValueProviderFactories;
        factories.RemoveType<FormValueProviderFactory>();
        factories.RemoveType<FormFileValueProviderFactory>();
        factories.RemoveType<JQueryFormValueProviderFactory>();
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: How this answer is different from @learner answer?

Answer (score 2):

I used `[DisableFormValueModelBinding]` but still got error, then i also use:

```
if (Request.ContentLength == 0)
                return BadRequest();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else is chasing ghosts regarding this error:
using net5 web api I had a controller with

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/fileupload/{reportId}")]
    [ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload(int reportId)
```

That wasn't a good idea. It gave the abovementionned error and I remembered having to pass on additional data via file attributes. That solved it for me. Just for completeness. This worked off course

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/fileupload")]
    [ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FileUpload()
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had added another filter which was intercepting the file. Even with the filters mentioned above I still got the issue. Removing the honey pot removed the error finally.

```
            .AddMvc(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter());
                // .... etc
                options.AddHoneyPot(); // This was causing the problem
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this error when send invalid form-data from client.
This is valid format:
NOTE: two minuses and new line in the end

```
<empty>
------------------------------8dac95867d24bd1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_login"

<data or empty>
------------------------------8dac95867d24bd1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_password"

<data or empty>
------------------------------8dac95867d24bd1
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_session"

<data or empty>
------------------------------8dac95867d24bd1--
<empty>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is bug about that in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4`. I updated this package to `2.1.12` version and it resolved.

Comment: Could you please provide reference to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was "postman" issue. I sent the file to the REST endpoint. And at some point I started to get this error, but the code was not changed.

I re-selected this file again in "postman" and everything worked as before.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MultipartFormDataContent to send the file, at the other side you will receive a `mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value` with an escaped *"* at the start & end (eg `"\"BoundaryValue\""`).

So by removing it, it started working for me.
The fix for me was to add this at receiver side: `.Replace("\"", "")`

```
mediaTypeHeader.Boundary.Value.Replace("\"", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to remove the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot IResourceFilter in DisableFormValueModelBindingAttribute.
work fine in .Net7

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was the payload... the `Content-Length` of the request was different from the actual length of the payload. The JavaScript code that was creating the HTTP POST was fixed to get rid of this issue.

Background: The original code looked similar to the Next.js code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71647581/how-do-i-pass-through-a-file-upload-request-from-a-next-js-api-to-another-api) except that it also included a `Content-Length` header that was different from the length of the body. And it was because the body was corrupted by body parser function. The solution is in that question.