# Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have some weird problem which happens to only 1 user of let's say 50.
AFAIK He's using Chrome

When he uploads file there's `Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.` being thrown

Here's my endpoint:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<JsonResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file, int type, string otherParam)
```

The thing is that I have middleware which logs every request, so it is reading requests and setting body position to 0

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Services;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;
using Serilog;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Common.Users;

public class LoggerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public LoggerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext ctx)
    {
        var request = await FormatRequest(ctx.Request, ctx);
        Log.Information(request);
        await next(ctx);
    }

    //hack
    private string[] endpoints_with_passwords = new string[] { "/Account/ChangePassword", "/Login" };

    private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request, HttpContext ctx)
    {
        Log.Information("Entering Logging Middleware");

        request.EnableRewind();
        var length = Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength);

        // in order to prevent having content of large files in logs...
        if (length > 30000)
            return $"file with length: {length} sent by User: '{ctx?.User?.Identity?.Name}'";

        var buffer = new byte[length];
        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        // "hack" in order to do not log passwords
        if (endpoints_with_passwords.Contains(request.Path.Value))
        {
            Log.Information("endpoints with password");
            try
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginModel>(bodyAsText);
                var ip = request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
                bodyAsText = $"IP: {ip} - UserName: {data?.UserName}";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EmailService.SendExceptionEmail(ex);
                Log.Error(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        Log.Information("Body Position = 0");
        request.Body.Position = 0;

        return $"User: '{ctx?.User?.Identity?.Name}' {Environment.NewLine} {request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {Environment.NewLine} {request.QueryString} {Environment.NewLine} {bodyAsText}";
    }
}
```

I thought that early return in

```
if (length > 30000)
    return $"file with length: {length} sent by User: '{ctx?.User?.Identity?.Name}'";
```

may cause problems, but when file's too large, then I'm receiving `Request body too large.`

so that's different error

Here's SeriLog which shows difference

Logs:
Working fine upload by other User:

```
2020-01-22 14:35:13.003 +01:00 [INF] User: 'A' 
 http localhost:5004/File/AddAttachment/1/attachment
 ?_=1579699970169 
 ------WebKitFormBoundarywlRNAu9AuOB6xBUD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="some.docx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
2020-01-22 14:35:13.083 +01:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "AddAttachment", controller = "File"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult] AddAttachment(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile, Int32, System.String) on controller Controllers.FileController (APP).
2020-01-22 14:35:13.083 +01:00 [INF] Authorization was successful.
```

Broken, sent by this (above mentioned) one particular User:

```
2020-01-24 16:29:24.677 +01:00 [INF] User: 'B' 
 http localhost:5004/File/AddAttachment/1/attachment
 ?_=1579711474176 
2020-01-24 16:29:24.677 +01:00 [INF] Route matched with {action = "AddAttachment", controller = "File"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult] AddAttachment(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile, Int32, System.String) on controller Controllers.FileController (APP).
2020-01-24 16:29:24.677 +01:00 [INF] Authorization was successful.
2020-01-24 16:29:27.381 +01:00 [ERR] 01/24/2020 16:29:25: Exception! (...) Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.
```

anybody has an idea what may go wrong? or how to debug that?

.NET Core 2.1

We're posting those files via JS.

Edit:
Issue on GH https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18087

Comment: Let us know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867343/unexpected-end-of-stream-the-content-may-have-already-been-read-by-another-comp) does not help for your ```Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.```

Comment: @WilliamW I've seen that, but wouldnt it mean that every file upload request would have this problem instead of **only** one user? I'm not even able to reproduce this error, but I'm constantly receiving exceptions when that one user is sending file.

Comment: If it is always only 1 particular user, then the problem likely lies with their web browser. I'd suggest removing the logging middleware, if that fixes the issue then you know where to look.

Comment: @IanKemp I decided to give a try with that attribute, but still middleware is ON. If problem will still occur, then I'll remove middleware also. Why like that instead of disabling both at once? Because I'd also want to learn what caused it, meanwhile otherwise I wouldnt be sure.

Comment: Had an issue like that that sounds very similar, we updated Microsoft.AspNetCore.App packages and the problem went away.
Also not sure if you are located in an EU country, but logging raw requests like that could lead to interesting GDRP issues :)

Comment: @ThomasSchmidt Thanks for pointing out, but I'm not exactly sure how does it violates GDPR if I'm logging data that's also in database? You mean that if User removes something from app(so from db also), then it'd be still accessible from logs?

Comment: My guess that it could be some Chrome extension messing up with file upload. Any chance to ask the client to try a file upload it in Incognito mode?

Comment: @PavelShastov it's tricky, but possible, but what kind of Chrome extension would be able to mess with file upload in that way? I tried messing with network during upload and I couldnt reproduce this exception

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be caused by a user interrupting file upload. Why don't you try reproducing the issue like that?

1. Start uploading a big file
2. Close the browser tab
3. Expect the error

Comment: I tried to reproduce it by e.g trying to upload 30 files at once, uploading big files and disconnecting cable / disabling network card and so on. I'm unable to reproduce this exception