# Failed to read the request form. Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.."

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, angular14

I'm tying to upload `formData` object from Angular v14 to Asp.Net v6 Rest API and i'm facing that error

```
Failed to read the request form. Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.
```

How can I solve that error?

**It's ASP.NET REST API side data**

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Contents { get; set; }
}
```

**It's entity class for db**

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "image")]
    public byte[] Contents { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller's class**

```
[HttpPost]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public IActionResult PostAdv([FromForm] AdvModel model)
{
    try
    {
        Advertisement entity = new Advertisement();
        entity.Id = model.Id;
        entity.Name = model.Name;
        entity.Price = model.Price;
        entity.Description = model.Description;
        entity.Features = model.Features.ToEntityList();
                
        foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(ms);
                    entity.Images.Add(new Image { Contents = ms.ToArray() });
                }
            }
        }
        
        new AdvHandler().PostAdv(entity);
        return Created(Request.Path, entity.ToModel());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, ex); //Internal server error;
    }
}
```

**It's angular side data**

**Image model's class**

```
export interface Image {
    id: number,
    file: File
}
```

**Component**

```
export class PostAdvComponent implements OnInit {

  advForm: FormGroup;
  @Input() adv: Advertisement;
  files: File[] = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private advertisementService: AdvertisementsService, changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.advForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
      price: ['', Validators.required],
      description: ['', Validators.required],
      images: this.fb.array([
        this.addImages()
      ]),
      features: this.fb.array([
        this.addFeatures()
      ])

    });

    this.advForm.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
      this.logValidationErrors(this.advForm);
    });

    //this.initializeObj();
    //this.addAdvertisement();
  }
  addFeatures(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      name: ['', Validators.required]
    })
  }
  addImages(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      id: [0],
      file: [null, Validators.required]
    })
  }
  uploadImage(event: any) {
    this.files = event.target.files;
  }

  addAdvertisement() {
    this.mapFormValuesToAdvModel();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('name', this.adv.name);
    formData.append('price', this.adv.price);
    formData.append('description', this.adv.description);
    const f = this.adv.features.length;
    for(let i=0; i < f; i++) {
      formData.append('name',this.adv.features[i].name)
    } 
    
    for(let i=0; i < this.files.length; i++) {
      formData.append('file',this.files[i],this.files[i].name)
    }
    
    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    });
    
    this.advertisementService.postAdvertisement(formData)
      .subscribe(add => {
        console.log(add);
      });
  }

  mapFormValuesToAdvModel() {
    this.adv.name = this.advForm.value.name;
    this.adv.price = this.advForm.value.price;
    this.adv.description = this.advForm.value.description;
    this.adv.images = this.advForm.value.images;
    this.adv.features = this.advForm.value.features;
  }
}
```

**Services**

```
postAdvertisement(formData: FormData): Observable<Advertisement> {

    return this.http.post<Advertisement>(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/advertisements',formData ,{
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
           'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
         })
       })
  }
```

I'm expecting to receive data in model object in Controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out while testing that when I remove your headers, I can receive the passed data in the controller. Not sure if this will work for you, but you can try.

Remove this:

```
{
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
       'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
    })
}
```

Test Result:
[image]

I've tried some of the solutions here, but none of them worked. If you have no other solutions, you can try this link to see if there is a solution that works for you: [Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49867343/unexpected-end-of-stream-the-content-may-have-already-been-read-by-another-comp)

Comment: Thanks a lot.Yeah it's work for me after removing header.